# how retrieve data from firebase with unknown id?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this record in firebase

```
"log" : {
    "-Kn-mUmVEN_i9ogWFTK-" : {
      "kit" : {
        "date" : "20170619",
        "time" : "0725",
        "id" : "1"
      }
    }
  }
```

how can I get the kit object? the uid is unknown.

Comment: By what criterion do you want to get the record then?

Comment: I got this json using this:
    var log = rootRef.child('log').once('value')
        .then( snapshot => {
            console.log(snapshot.val());
        });
but if I try to access the kit I got undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using the `Object.keys()` function:

```js
var log = {
    "-Kn-mUmVEN_i9ogWFTK-" : {
        "kit" : {
            "date" : "20170619",
            "time" : "0725",
            "id" : "1"
        }
    }
};

// Get the first key in log
var uid = Object.keys(log)[0]; 

// Get the kit object
var kit = log[uid].kit;        
console.log(kit);
```